# Super column from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have five columns in a dataframe as below :

```
Name, address, phone_number, height, weight
```

I want these columns to have a higher level column such as personal details having name, address and phone_number and physical parameters having height and weight.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please post some sample data with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data has only five columns, you can try:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('personal details', 'name'), 
                                           ('personal details', 'address'),
                                           ('personal details', 'phone_number'),
                                           ('physical details', 'height'),
                                           ('physical details', 'weight')
                                          ])
```

Comment: This should say MultiIndex, not MultipleIndex.